# Second image taking more than the web page in bootstrap when two images are put side by side

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[Image for the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ViLWR.jpg)I dont know why the 2nd image is taking more screen than 8 parts and getting out just not fitting in the 8 parts...and because of that I need to scroll right...

Here is my html code:

```
<div class="row">

      <div class="col-sm-3" >

        <img src="../img/1stimg.jpg" >
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-9">

          <img src="../img/2ndimg.jpg" >

     </div>

    </div>
```

This is my css code:

```
body{
font-family: 'Abhaya Libre', serif;
}

html,body
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.row img {
     max-width:100%;
     height:auto
}


.row { margin-left:0;margin-right:0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this helper from Bootstrap and remove .row img:

```
<img src="..." class="img-responsive">
```

Your image now will be responsive.

Comment: It made the first image shrink down and the second image is ok. what to do?